# How will you map the permission control between two entities?

Tags: database-design, schema

I have the following entities: Producer, Consumer.

```
A Producer produces Food for the Consumer. 
A Consumer consumes Food produced by the Producer.
```

Now I am tasked to design a schema which maps which **consumers can eat food produced by each producer**.

As an example, I have Producers p1, p2, p3 and Consumers c1, c2, c3.

```
   c1  c2  c3
p1  N   Y   N
p2  Y   N   N
p3  N   N   Y

where N = No and Y = Yes
```

Keep in mind that

1. the number of consumers and producers will keep growing.
2. the default state of whether a consumer can eat food from a new producer is **No**

How should I define this schema?

Answer (score 0):

One approach I thought of is to create a table

producer_consumer_allowed (producer_id, consumer_id).

A consumer is allowed to consume food from a producer if an entry for both this producer and consumer exist in this table.

Whenever we add a new producer, we do not need to do anything since the default state of consumers-producers is No.

Whenever we add consumers, we also do not need to add entires into this table since the default state is also No.